# SVN Mirroring using svn+ssh

Tags: svn

I'm in the process of configuring a redundant SVN server setup to ensure high availability. I've successfully installed SVN on both servers and initialized the repository. Additionally, I've set up passwordless SSH login for seamless authentication. However, in order to automate the process, I've opted for the (svn+ssh) protocol.

Whenever I attempt to execute the command

```
svnsync synchronize svn+ssh://svnsync@slavesrv.example.com/repo/testrepo --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --source-username=svnsync
```

I encounter an error message stating

```
"No more credentials or we tried too many times."
```

However, if I include `--source-password` with the password in plain text, the command executes successfully.

Could you please advise on how to implement passwordless authentication for this process?

I have tried making adjustments to my SSH configuration, I'm still encountering issues

Comment: Sounds like using a key that has no password setup should pull it off.... _or_ use sshpass if possible.